# Post-structuralist view of physics?

Tags: epistemology, philosophy-of-science, philosophy-of-language

What is the post-structuralist approach to natural sciences, especially physics?

Maybe post stucturalism is a bit too scattered to ask for a specific clear position, but what are the common ideas of the people associated with this line of thought?

The question is mainly motivated by me wondering about the role of objective reality as well as the posibility to describe the world by means of physical theories and how the mathamtical abstractions are able to connect to worldly things.

Comment: I do not believe that there is anyone who professes to hold a post-structuralist view of natural sciences in general, much less physics. Where have you heard this characterization? Can you provide some context for your question?

Comment: @CodyGray: I'm afraid this will not be very helpful. I came accross [four papers](http://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2007/03/a_topos_foundation_for_theorie.html) on a project, which aims at implementing quantum logic on a more fundamental level in the foundations of physical theories by introduction of some non-set-theoretic ideas. Motivated by this and to get a clearer picture in general, I'm currently trying to separate seductive aspects of language from model building. That's why I'm interested in the topic. If there is literature on this I don't have to come up with everything on my own.

Comment: To me this reads more like a fishing expedition than a clear and focused concern; I want to underscore @Cody's request for additional context and would encourage you to reformulate the question to include this context so as to be a bit more self-contained. Keep in mind great questions ask for explanations about very specific problems encountered in the study of philosophy

Comment: @JosephWeissman: Is it too vague? Oh boy, with 2.7 questions per day, Philosophy SE will be closed at one point (putting it cautiously). I don't know if downvoting the question is the right approach. I'm not a student of philosophy, where can I find a reference for the "great questions ask for explanations about very specific problems encountered in the study of philosophy"?

Comment: One concern I might mention here is encouraging high quality questions, i.e., that are clear and reasonably scoped, specific, and on-topic (about challenges encountered while studying philosophy.) Please consider reviewing our FAQ for more details on what sort of questions the community thinks are going to be most constructive.

Comment: In particular, the use of the term "post-structuralism" strikes me as problematic given the lack of specificity and theoretical context. What might you be reading that has made this concern an urgent or important one for you? What might you have found out so far? Etc. I am closing for the time being pending some further development of the question

Comment: @NickKidman What I think most people neglect is that we aren't asking for anything radical when we say "good question." A reference for such a question? Any one of the hundreds of good questions with a decent number of votes here.

Comment: structuralism is has been a strong current in mathematics since the early part of the 20C. It hasn't really touched physics yet. Sometimes they import tools built from the structuralist point of view, but they don't import the view itself. So I don't see that physicists themselves see physics as structuralist, never-mind post-structuralist. Other peple may, say sociologist\historians of science but then they would be using a different idea of structuralism

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's difficult to answer this question the way it is currently framed, but I'll give it a shot, and re-write if you refine the question.

First, we need to figure out who we mean by "post-structuralists".  There's a pretty diverse of people who generally get this label applied to them (and very few, if any, who use it as a self-appellation), and these folks have a pretty wide set of interests.  However, we can safely say that there are not many among who have taken it upon themselves to comment directly on physics or the natural sciences.

Second: the role of objective reality and its relation to mathematical abstractions is a difficult and complex one, and has been the subject of much work in the phenomenological tradition, so to the extent that some of the "post-structuralists" are also phenomenologists, you'll see some overlapping concerns.

In broad terms, I don't think there's *anyone* who questions that there is something that *appears to us* as "objective reality", and the point of view of a phenomenological analysis, we can "bracket" the ontological status of the ultimate referent-- in other words, we can take a fictionalist approach.  And, similarly, I don't think there's anyone who doubts that mathematical abstractions (as in physics) provide a *good enough* description of our world for pragmatic purposes.  Put another way: the caricature of post-structuralist thought that some physicists hold (and attack) in the so-called "Science Wars" is a straw man, and the "War" is being fought in the minds of these scientists only.  Arkady Plotnitsky makes this case quite well [here](http://pmc.iath.virginia.edu/text-only/issue.197/plotnitsky.197).

**EDIT:**  Since the question has been supplemented, I'll supplement my answer a bit.  The question described in the comments seems to actually be a bit broader, the task of "trying to separate seductive aspects of language from model building."  This is not limited, on the one hand, to physics or natural science, nor limited to post-structuralism.  Rather, the question comes down to the relationship between the map and the territory, between the *explanandum* and the *explanans*.  Most (non-Platonist) philosophers recognize that the correlation between the two will never be *perfect*, and that a better question is if the description is *adequate to the phenomenon.*  To answer whether the description in the four papers referenced is adequate for its intended purpose is beyond my knowledge or interest-- I scrupulously avoid anything with the word "Quantum" in it-- but I would hope that a careful reading of the texts would allow an ideal reader to ascertain whether the authors have been able to overcome the seductions of their own formalizations, and recognize the necessary leakage referred to above.

Comment: 1. In your answer you focus on reality, I'm maybe more interested in the model of it. My concern is that the idea that people read theories differently is strange if the theories are to explain one world in one way. How could that be. I mean how can there be different preceptions for something which is supposed to be universal, namely the physical explaition (math) to what is assumed to appear to everyone (say, the lighting). 2. Who would you say are the real and classical post-stucturalists. I'd like to read into it more and then maybe I'll find my own explaination - that is, interpretation.

Comment: In answer to your questions, let me first ask: what led you to this question? What is your interest in post-structuralism, if you haven't already identified what post-structuralists you are interested in? Setting that aside, though: it shouldn't be surprising that there are different theoretical explanations for the same phenomenon, and the fact that the perception of the phenomenon may be universal has no bearing on this; furthermore, there is a limit to the kinds of explanations that mathematics can provide-- math and Newtonian physics can tell us how fast a body will fall, but not *why*.

Comment: I have added a comment to the original post, which adds some context.

Comment: (Regarding the edit: Just to make that point clear, you write "The revised question..." but I didn't change the question. I don't ask for answers to the questions, which are my motivations for asking the question posted above. And the problem might be not limited to physics or science, but thats my interest here at least. I also don't ask for review of the content of these particular papers, these are merely the context in which the broader question came up.)

Comment: Noted. (And fixed language regarding "the revised question".)